# How to mount SD card if I installed with NOOBS?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, noobs

I installed Raspbian with NOOBS. However, when I try to read the files on my SD card using a card reader, I just get all the NOOBS stuff and not my Raspbian files.

Is there a way to get to the Raspbian files?

Comment: What OS are you using? I am assuming not Linux. You can run a live Linux distro to access the partitions that you can't access. You can also use the Pi and a card reader.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a Windows computer the Linux filesystem will not show up.

You can use a program like [DiskInternals Linux Reader](https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/), and the Raspbian filesystem should show up on the SD card. I've used the software before as a way of getting important documents off the SD card quickly before formatting the card for something else.